# Andriod: Navigation bar hides, but activity is not fill screen

Tags: android

Trying to create simple application with fullscreen video playing. 
Navigation bar hides, but activity is not filling the screen.
What am I missing?

activity:

```
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="my.test.app2.VViewer">
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout >
```

```
public class VViewer extends AppCompatActivity {
    private VideoView myVideo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vviewer);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        );
    }
@Override
protected void onResume ()
    {
        super.onResume();
        myVideo=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        myVideo.setVideoPath(MP4FileName);
        myVideo.start();
    }
```

theme for activity

```
    <style name="AppTheme.FullscreenTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

[image: emulator]

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

Answer (score 0):

My code works fine for 16:9 screen devices. Problems only on 18:9 devices.
I don't understand why, but adding

```
    <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
```

to application section of android manifest file solves the problem.